# Data binding how i create object for SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I cannot create an object for SupportMapFragment while using data binding.

code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.mission_fragment_mission_detail_accounts, container, false);
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.accountmap);
    return mBinding.getRoot();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Has the fragment been instantiated yet?  When you create a fragment in the fragment manager you assign it an ID for the stack, and then retrieve that instance after it has been created.

After a new fragment is added to the fragment manager you can retrieve it by id.